# Visual Studio Code Java Access Restriction

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, jar, visual-studio-code

I installed the Java Language Support from RedHat extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java), but I am getting this error for JavaFX applications.

Error:

```
[Java] Access restriction: The type 'Application' is not API (restriction on required library '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar')
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

How can I make the error go away? As you can see it is underlining everything red if the classes belong to that jar file.

Comment: change your jre

Comment: I'm using the openjre8. What should I use?

Comment: downgrade it to anyone which you have and later upgrade again

Comment: Ok, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Gradle, you can integrate the access rule directly into `build.gradle` using the eclipse plugin:

```
import org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.AccessRule

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

eclipse {
    classpath {
        file {
            whenMerged {
                def jre = entries.find { it.path.contains 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER' }
                jre.accessRules.add(new AccessRule('0', 'javafx/**'))
                jre.accessRules.add(new AccessRule('0', 'com/sun/javafx/**'))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That works for me.

---

PS Solution was originally posted here: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/120

Comment: it works for me too, but I still didn't get it. why the hell this error is coming up?